# How to count the distinct column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

E.g:

with the `select query` I got below result:

```
columnA columnB
type1   typea
type2   typea
type3   typeb
type4   typec
type5   typed
type6   typed
type7   typed
```

with the `DISTINCT` I only got the `distinct result`,but I also want to get the `total number` of each distinct.

and now I want to get the **total number** of

```
typea,typeb,typec and typed.
```

Just like:

```
columnB total
typea   2
typeb   1
typec   1
typed   3
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to get results by type:

```
SELECT columnB, COUNT(*) AS 'total'
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY columnB;
```

This should give you exactly the result you are looking for.

> **MySQL Documentation:** [11.16.1 GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html)